# Append and prepend text to a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to append and prepend each value in a column called description with `<p></p>`

So I need to append each value with `<p>` and append with `</p>`

So the following `test` will become `<p>test</p>`.

Could anyone suggest a query that will handle this?

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE mytable SET description = CONCAT("<p>", description, "</p>")
```

Comment: What advantage does using a non-standard function `CONCAT` have over `+`?

Comment: It works? `SELECT  "A" +  "B"` -> 0 (MySQL Server Version: 5.6.15)

Comment: Wow, you're right.  How did MySQL manage to get something so basic so horribly wrong?

Comment: Haha, I don't know. Must be historical reasons :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
update mytable
set col = '<p>' + col + '</p>';
```

or else you can use the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function%5Fconcat) function like

```
update mytable
set col = CONCAT('<p>', col, '</p>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update column using [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
 UPDATE table_name SET description = CONCAT("<p>", description, "</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET description=concat('<p>',description ,'</p>');
```